# how to align multiple tikzpictures horizonally and vertically in one single PDF file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, alignment

I hope to align multiple figures plotted by tikzpictures.

As shown in the below codes, I draw eight figures, they are automatically shown in 4 rows and 2 columns, but I want them to be in 2 rows and 4 columns.
Are there related methods to align them as we want, for example in 2 rows and 4 columns in this example?

Besides, I want to have them in one single PDF file and with no or narrow borders, so I use {standalone} for \documentclass.

Thank you very much

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}%border=3mm, 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{width=5cm,height=5cm,grid style={dashed}}
\begin{filecontents}{plottedtata.txt}
x    y1        y2        y3        y4        y5        y6        y7        y8
x    m         m         m         m         m         m         m         m
1    0.6951    0.6678    0.6753    0.9160    0.4609    0.4714    0.4735    0.1917
2    0.0680    0.8444    0.0067    0.0012    0.7702    0.0358    0.1527    0.7384
3    0.2548    0.3445    0.6022    0.4624    0.3225    0.1759    0.3411    0.2428
4    0.2240    0.7805    0.3868    0.4243    0.7847    0.7218    0.6074    0.9174
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[
  skip first n=6, % 2+4 for filecontents header
]{plottedtata.txt}{\plottedtata}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(1), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=1,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(2), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=2,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(3), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=3,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(4), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=4,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(5), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=5,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(6), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=6,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(7), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=7,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(8), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=8,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I changed the `align` tag to `alignment`.  `align` is specific to a multi-line math environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the use of `varwidth`, I removed the use of the `figure` environment, and I used a stack to separate the top 4 figures from the bottom.

```
\documentclass{standalone}%border=3mm, 
\usepackage{tikz,stackengine}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{width=5cm,height=5cm,grid style={dashed}}
\begin{filecontents}{plottedtata.txt}
x    y1        y2        y3        y4        y5        y6        y7        y8
x    m         m         m         m         m         m         m         m
1    0.6951    0.6678    0.6753    0.9160    0.4609    0.4714    0.4735    0.1917
2    0.0680    0.8444    0.0067    0.0012    0.7702    0.0358    0.1527    0.7384
3    0.2548    0.3445    0.6022    0.4624    0.3225    0.1759    0.3411    0.2428
4    0.2240    0.7805    0.3868    0.4243    0.7847    0.7218    0.6074    0.9174
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[
  skip first n=6, % 2+4 for filecontents header
]{plottedtata.txt}{\plottedtata}
%\begin{figure}
\stackunder{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(1), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=1,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(2), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=2,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(3), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=3,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(4), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=4,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(5), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=5,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(6), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=6,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(7), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=7,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(8), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=8,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

Per OP's follow-up comment, if one needs 3 or more rows of figures, use the syntax `\Shorstack{<first row>\\<second row>\\<third row>...}`, where the row separator is set via `\setstackEOL{\\}` (default <space>).  The interrow gap can be pre-set via `\setstackgap{S}{6pt}`.  The default alignment is centered, which can be reset with `\renewcommand\stackalignment{l` or `c` or `r}.`

```
\documentclass{standalone}%border=3mm, 
\usepackage{tikz,stackengine}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{width=5cm,height=5cm,grid style={dashed}}
\begin{filecontents}{plottedtata.txt}
x    y1        y2        y3        y4        y5        y6        y7        y8
x    m         m         m         m         m         m         m         m
1    0.6951    0.6678    0.6753    0.9160    0.4609    0.4714    0.4735    0.1917
2    0.0680    0.8444    0.0067    0.0012    0.7702    0.0358    0.1527    0.7384
3    0.2548    0.3445    0.6022    0.4624    0.3225    0.1759    0.3411    0.2428
4    0.2240    0.7805    0.3868    0.4243    0.7847    0.7218    0.6074    0.9174
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[
  skip first n=6, % 2+4 for filecontents header
]{plottedtata.txt}{\plottedtata}
%\begin{figure}
\setstackgap{S}{6pt}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\Shortstack{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(1), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=1,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(2), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=2,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(3), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=3,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(4), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=4,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(5), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=5,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(6), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=6,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(7), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=7,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [color=black,grid=major,use units, y unit=m,xlabel=(8), ylabel=y,
        every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=3pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={thick, minor tick length=1.7pt, black},
        xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick={1,2,3,4}, tick align=outside, minor x tick num=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, minor y tick num=1]
        \addplot[draw=red,line width=1,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}] table [x index=0,y index=8,]{\plottedtata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Steven, thank you very much for your answer, it really solves this question.
But I find that, if we have more figures, for example, if we want to have 3 rows and 4 columns, that is 12 figures in total. Then the "9th-to-12th" figures will not be below the "5th-to-8th" figures as we expect, but on the right of the "1st-to-4th" ones.
In the more figures example, how could we obtain the effect?

Comment: @wxwuse Per the stackengine documentation, use `\setstackEOL{\\}` to make the double-backslash (or any other convenient syntax) a row separator, and then use `\Shortstack{<first row content>\\<second row content>\\<third row content>...}`.  The dead space between stacked rows is controlled by (and can be pre-set with) `\setstackgap{S}{<gap value>}` (default 3pt).

Comment: @wxwuse I have provided an **ADDENDUM** to explain this concept.

Comment: Dear Steven, thank you again for your answer, it really solves this question.

Comment: @wxwuse You are welcome.  In order to best indicate to the community that a question of yours has been answered to your satisfaction, you may click the check mark to the left of the one answer (if there are several answers) that best answers your question.  This is called "accepting" an answer.

Comment: Dear Steven, thank you very much for your suggestion.